# Why is the field computed by "IGNITE" return a "BIGINT" type? In theory, it should be a "DECIMAL" type, because the result contains decimal numbers

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ignite

Ignite version:2.7.0.

Here are the expressions I use：

`SUM(A1) / SUM(A2) / 1000`

A1, A2 are all integers.

In Ignite,I got type `BIGINT`.

In MySQL,I got type `DECIMAL`.

The results of MySQL are in line with my expectations, because the data does contain decimal numbers.

If I use the following expression：

`SUM(A1) / SUM(A2) / 1000.0`

The result is correct.

But why can't Ignite derive the right type?

Comment: Integer division results in an integer, not in a decimal. In my opinion, MySQL's behaviour is the deviation from the norm, but I don't have the SQL standard at hand right now to verify my claim (I do know that for decimal division the behaviour regarding precision and scale is implementation defined)

Comment: In MySQL the result is the scale of the first operand plus the value of the div_precision_increment system variable (4 by default).

Comment: FWIW, I agree with @MarkRotteveel, but I'm not really clear what the question is here? You identify what it's doing and a workaround. This is more a difference of philosophy than a bug -- it's not that Ignite _can't_ derive the right type. What would an accepted answer look like?

Comment: @StephenDarlington I just looked it up in the SQL:2016 specification, and both behaviours are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question *"But why can't Ignite derive the right type?"*, is that it does derive the right type. Ignite clearly applies the rules for integer division (just like Java does) when dividing integers, or it applies a rule that yields a result with a scale of 0 for integer division (which yields a similar results, although it can have slightly rounding rules compared to integer division).

This is perfectly fine according to the SQL:2016 (ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016) standard, *6.29 <numeric value expression>*:

> Otherwise, the declared type of both operands of a dyadic arithmetic
>   operator is exact numeric and the declared type of the result is an
>   implementation-defined exact numeric type, with precision and scale
>   determined as follows:
>
> i) Let S1 and S2 be the scale of the first and second operands
>   respectively.
>
> ii) The precision of the result of addition and subtraction is
>   implementation-defined, and the scale is the maximum of S1 and S2.
>
> iii) The precision of the result of multiplication is
>   implementation-defined, and the scale is S1 + S2.
>
> iv) **The precision and scale of the result of division are
>   implementation-defined**

Note that the behaviour of MySQL is also allowed within these rules.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the right type or avoid handling the wrong type.

1. Although the `BIGINT` type is derived from meta information, the data type is still `DECIMAL` when reading data.
2. Treat all `BIGINT` types as `DECIMAL` types.